# How to get the path of an imported Angular module?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get the BarComponent's path in the code-snippet below? Basically I need to get '../bar/bar.component'. For a module loaded from a package like Component module I'd like to get "@angular/core". Is it possible?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BarComponent } from '../bar/bar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html'
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  barComponentPath;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.barComponentPath = ""; // ?
  }
}
```

I created a playable sample here https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically create a local npm package for your component. It is often time-consuming so we all end up by using .. paths. "@angular" is npm package and it can be found in npm_modules so that is why it can be loaded like this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need to get the path or package name of the loaded module in the code itself (e.g. in  ngOnInit).